# Marketo activities.json API endpoint causing a timeout

Tags: marketo

I am trying to use the [Marketo activities.json API endpoint](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-lead-activities/), and I am getting a timeout everytime I try. I have set the cURL timeout to 25 seconds and I am using a valid `nextPageToken` parameter to filter the results. The timeframe is yesterday and today.

When I try other endpoints (`lists.json`, `activities/pagingtoken.json`, `leads.json`, `lists.json`, and `stats/usage/last7days.json`) I get a response and my request does not timeout.

Here is the request I am making to `activities.json`:

```
method: "GET"
url: "https://[marketo-id].mktorest.com/rest/v1/activities.json"
parameters: Array
(
    [nextPageToken] => [paging-token]
    [listId] => [list-id]
    [activityTypeIds] => 24
    [access_token] => [access-token]
)
```

Why am I getting a timeout just for the `activities.json` endpoint? Is this  API endpoint broken or down?

Answer (score 1):

The global timeout for Marketo's REST API is 30 seconds, can you first try adjusting your local timeout to match this?  If you remove list ID from from the call what happens?

Comment: I updated the timeout to 60 seconds and I am still getting a timeout from the `activities.json` endpoint. I independently tested removing the `listId` parameter as well and that did not make any difference. Everything I try leads me to believe this endpoint is not functioning.

Comment: More info: when I remove the parameter `activityTypeIds` I get the following error: `[code] => 1002 [message] => Missing value for required parameter 'activityTypeIds'`. When that is in the request, I get a timeout. I am not doing anything additional but hitting that endpoint. No matter what I get a timeout every time. The fact that an error is returned yet when everything is correct I get a timeout leads me to believe there is an definite error with this endpoint.

Comment: I'd say to open a support ticket at this point.  You shouldn't be getting a timeout for a basic operation like that.  Be sure to include some example calls with the ticket.

Comment: How can I open a support ticket? When I look here http://developers.marketo.com/support/overview/ I see just stackoverflow and twitter as the two channels available for help with Marketo.

Comment: You can open tickets on support.marketo.com, but if you aren't an authroized contact for the support entitlement you'll probably need to have your marketo admin or marketing ops specialist do this for you.